Java Runtime Environment (JRE) with module support?
In searching for a JRE to run my (javafx-based) desktop application I found JRE version 8 from here https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp . This is the default, and this is where I am redirected when clicking the JRE link on Oracle's website (https://www.oracle.com/downloads/#category-java)
But, the JRE does not support --module-path obviously because it's too old.
What are my options for running my app on non-developer machines? (note the JRE is 60MB and the JDK is 190MB).
I am afraid to ask why the default JRE download is too old?
My app compiles with openjdk 17.0.9 2023-10-17

Duplicate question. Replaced by jlink so that you make your own JRE - which could even include your own modules so that --module-path isn't needed

This is - for example - explained in https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular

@MarkRotteveel  A helloworld app is like making skyscrappers with plasticine in nursery school. The link you posted comes up often. In reality it is quite a lame attempt to tackle this problem.

I'm specifically talking about the $JAVA_HOME/bin/jlink --module-path $PATH_TO_FX_MODS:mods --add-modules hellofx --output hellofx will create the appropriate JRE (or custom runtime image) specifically for your application. The fact your asking if you can use a Java 8 JRE suggests to me that you haven't even tried this route.

You have two questions here.  The one in the title "Java Runtime Environment (JRE) with module support?" -> The answer to that is straightforward (and I think you already know) -> any version of the JRE 9+, because that Java 9 is when module support was added to Java..

"What are my options for running my app on non-developer machines?" -> the answer to that is much more complex (too complex to comprehensively answer on StackOverflow IMO) and has many solutions, some of which are provided in Basil's answer.  To get a definitive answer, you probably need to ask a more focused question.

There is a difference between naming a solution, which doesn't help you much and providing a step-by-step guide on how to execute the solution, which can be quite involved.  For instance, the jpackage user guide or the badass jlink documentation - they are both equally massive.

There is an in-depth discussion of some options and details for creating custom JREs for distribution in the answer to How to properly get the JDK modules for a fat JavaFX jar using jdeps, but there is a good chance that will confuse you rather than help you.

@jewelsea the answer to that is straightforward (and I think you already know) -> any version of the JRE 9+, because that Java 9 is when module support was added to Java.. Where I can download that JRE 9+ then?!?! www.java.com lists only JRE8? Perhaps I did not search enough?

The JRE 8 at java.com is obsolete.  There are numerous providers of modern JREs (and JDKs), some include JavaFX.  For example Azul JRE FX or Liberica Full JRE, or without JavaFX,  Temurin, Corretto, Oracle,  OpenJDK.

tl;dr
Two vendors provide editions of their JDK/JRE products for Java 17, 21, and current 22 bundled with the modern generation of OpenJFX libraries implementing JavaFX: Azul Systems and BellSoft.
Details
Understand that JavaFX has never been a standard part of Java.
And understand that JavaFX is now implemented in the open-source project OpenJFX. That project is under continual active development, co-led by Oracle Corp and the Gluon company.
Years ago, Oracle chose to bundle JavaFX libraries with some of its JDK/JRE products. Then later they stopped bundling.
Oracle is but one of several vendors offering JDK/JRE products. See Java Is Still Free for an explanation of the Java ecosystem.
Some JDK/JRE vendors currently choose to bundle the JavaFX libraries implemented as OpenJFX in some editions of their products. I know of at least two such vendors:

Azul Systems
BellSoft

The Java Platform Module System arrived in 2017 in Java 9 and later. The vendors listed above offer JavaFX-bundles for the modularized LTS versions 11, 17, and 21, as well as the current version (now 22).
JavaFX 22 requires JDK/JRE 17 or later.
Alternatively, you can bundle the OpenJFX libraries within your app. And you can bundle a JRE within your app, and optionally slim down the JRE to include only the parts that your app uses.  The OpenJDK project offers tooling to assist: jlink and jpackage.
The cutting-edge technology uses GraalVM to produce a native app from your JavaFX project.

You asked:

But, the JRE does not support --module-path obviously because it's too old.

Java 9 and later has the Java Platform Module System (JPMS). Focus on the LTS versions (11, 17, 21) and current (22) as the other versions have reached EOL(End of Life). The latest versions of OpenJFX support Java 17 and later.

What are my options for running my app on non-developer machines?

If you have control over user machines, such as in an enterprise or education environment, consider having the sysadmins install a JRE that comes bundled with the necessary OpenJFX libraries.
In a niche market, perhaps you can require your users to install a JRE bundled with the OpenJFX libraries.
In a broad retail market, you’ll need to bundle both a JVM and the OpenJFX libraries within your app. The app marketplaces such as Apple App Store will accept such a product.

(note the JRE is 60MB and the JDK is 190MB).

You can greatly reduce that size by using the jlink tool with your JPMS modularized project.

I am afraid to ask why the default JRE download is too old?

The “why” is simply that Oracle later decided to stop bundling JavaFX libraries with their own JDK/JRE products.
But you are free to bundle the OpenJFX libraries within your app, at no cost.
And, you have the choice of obtaining more recent versions of Java JDK/JRE bundled with OpenJFX libraries from vendors other than Oracle. You can obtain free-of-cost products as well as products with paid support.

My app compiles with openjdk 17.0.9 2023-10-17

Then you can use OpenJFX 22 while compiling for Java 17.

I am trying for a week now to go with jpackage, jlink maven assembly and maven sprint-boot (assembly). They all fail miserably for me because of this or that module not found during packaging on dev machine. So, whatever I do they don't detect all deps. With the exception of spring-boot which only complains about javafx modules can not be run from jar. So I thought I bundle all the dependencies spring-boot found with my classess and create a tarball to distribute. So again at dead end.  Now, with jpackage I get the dreaded jlink failed with: Error: Module jdk.management.jfr not found

@bliako Building JavaFX apps is a  complex, frustrating, and trouble-prone process, unfortunately, the worst part of an otherwise excellent platform. I don’t have much experience there, so I cannot assist. I suggest you look for Answers and Comments posted here by expert jewelsea.

@bliako As noted, this can be a complex process. Given your use of Spring, which is not modular as of yet if I'm not mistaken, I would recommend that your own code should not be modular. In fact, forget modules entirely except for JavaFX and any modules from the JDK itself. Execute jpackage and put JavaFX on the --module-path and add the needed modules via --add-modules (or create the run-time image separately with jlink directly and point jpackage at it with --runtime-image). Then your code and all other dependencies should be included via --input (also see --main-jar).

That makes it so only JavaFX and Java SE/JDK modules are part of the modular run-time image. Your code and any other dependencies will be loaded from the class-path and, for the most part, function just like they would before Java 9. Node you may need to explicitly add certain modules, such as the jdk.crypto.xxx modules if you want to support SSL (i.e., if you want to support HTTPS endpoints).

You should try using jlink to make a compatible JRE from a JDK. Before using jlink, verify that the JDK you want to base the JRE on can run your application using appropriate class-path / module-path entries.
If that works, try to generate a JRE that just contains the modules you use such as JavaFX. For example:
set JAVAFX_MODS=C:\java\javafx-jmods-21
jlink --module-path "%JAVAFX_MODS%" --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.graphics --strip-debug --no-man-pages --no-header-files --output jre-fx

This means that you can use jre-fx\bin\java to launch any class that uses JavaFX without specifying JavaFX modules again.
Later, you could also use jlink to make a JRE with your own module, if you have correct dependences on JavaFX and set the module-path, the new JRE will contain everything needed to run your application:
jlink --module-path "%JAVAFX_MODS%;your-module-dir" --add-modules yourmodule --strip-debug --no-man-pages --no-header-files --output jre-all

With this new JRE - jre-all\bin\java - you only need to specific the launch class names, all modules are included.
If you need to distribute your application for other machines then look at jpackage to build installers - EXE/MSI on Windows or other packager for Mac/Linux. It can be setup to use your pre-generated JRE with jpackage --runtime-image jre-all or it can use jlink internally for you each time it is launched.

thanks, your first one-liner gave me hope, but alas Error: Module java.desktop not found, required by javafx.graphics java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.desktop not found, required by javafx.graphics

What JDK and JavaFX are you using?

openjdk version "17.0.9" 2023-10-17, javafx v22. I use maven to compile and run the app and does not complain about anything missing. In java -version I see OpenJDK Runtime Environment but that it is nowhere to be found for download (for the target OS) then I saw https://superuser.com/questions/1419880/does-openjdk-contain-a-jre which points to https://adoptium.net/en-GB/temurin/releases/ And at this point it becomes sureal, who are adoptium? and why should i trust their distribution and what if it compromises my target machines?

Ignore Maven for now. You are saying that if you run jdk-17\bin\jlink --module-path "somepath/to/javafx22-modules" --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.graphics --strip-debug --no-man-pages --no-header-files --output jre17-fx gives Module java.desktop not found ?

correct (and thank you for your help). and the module path is the path I extracted the jmods (from https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/), to clarify the jmods folder contains *.jmod files. The jlink executable is of v17.0.9 and i guess it is inistalled by openjdk (iam in linux and all these have been installed by the package manager). The javafx SDK is not being used at the moment, only the JMODS. Does perhaps javafx provide its own jlink which I should be using?

JDK provides jlink. Something doesn't look right with your JDK if java.desktop is missing. This should work and build a minimal dependencies to check: jdk-17\bin\jlink --add-modules java.desktop --strip-debug --no-man-pages --no-header-files --output jre17.desktop

nope, Error: --module-path is not specified and this runtime image does not contain jmods directory. And the jlink binary is provided by java-17-openjdk-devel of fedora package manager. the same which provides java and javac.

It likely you have installed a headless JDK, not a full JDK

thanks. By "headless" you mean no GUI components or not full-install? Unless you are sure I doubt what you said. It is not reasonable that the only fedora package which provides javac is lacking components. In any event I have managed to run the app on windows using the adoptium JRE. I will describe how in an answer

The answer by @BasilBourque lists the options for downloading JRE which supports latest java features and understand the --add-modules features. This is the accepted answer to my question.
However, I will outline here the whole process of packaging my app and its dependencies because, for my case, jlink kept complaining that it did not find basic dependencies, see comments under @DuncG 's answer.
I have also placed a demo at https://github.com/hadjiprocopis/javafx-uberjar

Create CLASSPATH, MODULEPATH and MODULES for your app. If you are using maven this is easy by parsing the output of mvn -X javafx:run@dry-run-cli to create said vars.

Collect the dependencies (jars) somehow. To me, it does not sound logical to download all these dependencies when I have maven which downloaded already these in its repository (located at ~/.m2/repository/...). So, I resorted to the spring-boot maven plugin which creates a JAR with all dependencies plus my app classes. This JAR warns with WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module ...' and I did not trust it to distribute it. In any event, this jar file now contains all the dependent jars in its lib/*. As a bonus it can contain OS-specific javafx jars for any other OSes you specify in the pom.xml
as a <dependency> with <classifier> set to linux,win,mac, etc.

The structure of the distribution zip/tar-ball will be:
a. lib dir to contain all 3rd-party jar dependencies, even module jars, even OS-specific jars e.g. javafx-media-22-ea+11-mac.jar, javafx-media-22-ea+11-win.jar, etc.
b. classes dir to contain your apps classes or a jar.
c. launchers dir to contain launcher scripts for your target OS(es).

The launcher script will in general be something like:
java -classpath "classes:lib/xyz.jar:..." --module-path "lib/javafx...jar:lib/..." --add-modules "javafx.base,..." com.myapp.Main
Note that in M$ the classpath separator ':' should be ';'


Now the last and biggest problem is to find a JRE which provides a java command which understands --module-path et.al. (which were introduced with java v9+). What prompted me to ask this question was the fact that oracle provides a JRE (via www.java.com) which supports java version 8!!!!! (When currently on java version 20 and counting). The oracle obviously knows all, so I will not dispute this decision. The fact is, that I am jreless after all this hard work.
All people answering this question (thank you all for your effort) suggested to create my own JRE using jlink. That did not work for me. It complains that it does not find basic dependency like java.base (using openJDK v17 on Linux Fedora installed via its package manager from package java-17-openjdk-devel : OpenJDK 17 Development Environment). In addition, the lame example hellofx assumes that my app is a module, which it isn't. Additionally, maven javafx:jlink fails as well (for me) with various dependencies not found. It is a mystery because maven compile javafx:run runs without problems.
Since creating my own JRE is not working for me, I resorted to downloading a JRE supplied by https://adoptium.net/en-GB/temurin/releases/ (I think it is associated with Eclipse). Is it safe? Is it "official"? I have no idea.
The answer by @Basil Bourque lists a few more options. (And actually is the accepted answer)
I have placed a demo at https://github.com/hadjiprocopis/javafx-uberjar
it runs on linux and can create a distribution zip archive for linux, mac and/or the unnamed-os.
It relies on your app being developed as a maven project because all the dependencies are collected via maven and spring-boot plugin. All the javafx depdendencies will be read from the local maven repository it uses for compiling and running your app. There is no need for you to download any third-party dependencies and keep parallel versions!
thanks for the help (but no thanks :))

Yes, the Adoptium project was transferred to the Eclipse Foundation after beginning in 2017 as AdoptOpenJDK.  See Wikipedia.  As for “safe”, the project is entirely open-source and publicly available. The JDK/JRE products have not only passed the TCK tests, they pass an additional suite of tests invented at the Adoptium project itself!

As for “official”, there is no official JDK/JRE. Java is a set of specifications published by Oracle. Anyone is free to develop an implementation of those specs, though using the trademark “Java” requires permission from Oracle. Several companies offer JDK/JRE products including Amazon, Microsoft, IBM, Red Hat, Oracle, SAP, Azul Systems, BellSoft, and more.

Regarding the test suites: TCK and AQAvit™ Verification.
